# Getting values of a POST multi-dimensional array with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony3 CRM that implements a form to create an invoice. In this form there is a list of different costs, such as labour, service and materials. I have coded this so it's in a multidimensional array since the user can create any number of fields with whatever they want.

An example of the post array:

```
[costings] => Array
(
    [labour] => 80.30
    [materials] => 75.00
    [service] => 43.50
    ....
)
```

I want to use Doctrine to get the data. To retrieve the costings array, I use this:

```
$request->request->get('costings');
```

But I do not know how to get the values within that array. I tried:

```
$costings->get('labour');
```

But I get a warning saying I'm trying to call `get()` on an array. Is there a way to do this or do I need to revert back to just using `$_POST`?

Comment: BTW, `Request` has nothing to do with Doctrine. It is part of Symfony's `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this, since you POST `costings` as normal array.

```
$costings = $request->request->get('costings');
$labourCostings = $costings['labour'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
$labour = $request->request->get('costings')['labour'];
```

?

If it doesn't work, try to dump the result of `$request->request->get('costings')`